# How does pair/vireo accessing work in Lambda Calculus?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

(DISCLAIMER SYNTAX: i am using λabc.exp instead of λa.λb.λc.exp)

TLDR/EASIER EXAMPLE:

```
V:= λgxf.f(ga)
GETG:= λa.a(g)

GETG V(N1 N2)
```

I wanna know if this is valid, ie. `GETG === N1`

FULL (what I'm actually doing):
I made a little chemistry model and my goal is to be able to use my data structures within a function.

```
V:= λgxf.f(gx)
ELEMENT:= λpnetf.f(pnet)
BONDDATA:= λab.Vab
NONMETAL:= V(N0 N0)
METAL:= V(N1 N1)
```

Notice that i made a list for a pair/vireo data.

(for anyone who's curious ELEMENT's parameter input is as follows: proton,neutron,electron,type)

Now I'll define my bonding function and element:

```
HYDROGEN:= ELEMENT(N1 N0 N1 NONMETAL)
H-PAIR:= BONDDATA(HYDROGEN HYDROGEN)

COVALENT:= ...placeholder
IONIC:= ...placeholder

BOND:= λab.a(AND is0(t(a)) is0(t(b))) b(AND is0(t(a)) is0(t(b)))COVALENTab IONICab

BOND H-PAIR === ?
```

As you could see I don't know if it is possible to access `t`(type) from `λa`even if you passed a list/pair data structure on to it. If ever this doesn't work why? and what will?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is not valid because I am only applying a as a parameter.

The way to do this is to define our own selectors for data structures.

fst:= λabcd.a
snd:= λabcd.b
and so on... preferably we could use church numerals with this.

selector:= λnabcd.EQnN1 a EQnN2 b EQnN3 c EQnN4 d

So in our bond function:
λab.AND is0(K(selectorN4a) KI(selectorN4b)) Covalentab... and so forth.

There may be a better way to do this but i am unaware of for now.